# Area under a given curve

Tags: calculus

Consider the given function $f(t)=\sin^2(\sin(\sin(t)))$. Show that on the interval $[0,x]$ the area under $f(t)$ is bounded above by $x^2$.

My concern is that I am not sure what it asks. That's why I'm not sure where to start. What does it mean when it says bounded above by $x^2$? What I know is that if it's bounded above, the upper function has to be $x^2$ but how can I relate it to the given function? I tried taking the Riemann sum but it doesn't make sense to me. Please help.

Comment: It means the integral of the function from $[0, x]$ is always less than $x^{2}$ evaluated at that same x. Thus, the anti-derivative over $[0, x]$ should always be less than $x^{2}$

Comment: @TyJensen: There's no such thing as "the anti-derivative."

Comment: THUS THE FUNCTION DEFINED BY THE INTEGRAL IN RESPECT TO $t$ SHOULD ALWAYS BE LESS THAN $x^{2}$

Comment: what theorems are you allowed to use?

Comment: @DonlansDonlans we are dealing with Riemann sums. I can't seem to get the limit of the Riemann sum. the function is too complicated for me

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $x > 0,$ you are supposed to show that 
$\int_0^x \sin^2(\sin(\sin(t)))\,\mathrm dt < x^2$. 
Note that  the left side of the inequality is a function of $x,$
$$ F(x) = \int_0^x \sin^2(\sin(\sin(t)))\,\mathrm dt, $$
so you are to show that $F(x) < x^2.$

Have you previously shown that $\sin(t) < t$ for any $t > 0$?

Using this fact, eventually you can show that $f(t) = \sin^2(\sin(\sin(t))) < t^2$
for any $t > 0,$
which implies that
$F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\,\mathrm dt < \int_0^x t^2\,\mathrm dt.$
That covers all the cases $0 \leq x \leq 3$ easily, and you can use the fact that
$f(t) < 1$ to cover $x > 3.$

But even better, you can show that $f(t) = \sin^2(\sin(\sin(t))) < t$
for any $t> 0,$ and therefore
$F(x) < \int_0^x t\,\mathrm dt.$

It turns out that using $x^2$ as an upper bound is quite generous.
You could do an upper Riemann sum with one rectangle,
though you might want to treat the case for $x > 1$ separately from the case for $0\leq x \leq 1$ since for large values of $x$ the height of the rectangle is usually greater than $f(x).$